# Error al importar componente en vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, importación, vite

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de práctica y me arroja el siguiente error:
**[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "/components/Products.jsx" from "src\App.jsx". Does the file exist?................................         ↑**

Aun cuando la direccion de mi archivo está bien escrita.

Comment: Por favor si es posible no agregues imágenes. En tal caso copia y pega lo que muestra tu consola de lo que trata el error

Comment: Hola Enzo, bienvenido, probaste con **"src/App.jsx"**?... mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Intenta agregando un punto al path estilo ./components/Products.jsx

Comment: ¡Hola!, tuve un error similar. En mi caso, al crear un componente en React, estaba declarado 'PropTypes' pero su valor nunca se leía. Comente la siguiente línea y logre que funcionara:
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';